# MSBuild failed to create .xap error

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build WP8 app with cordova, but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: MSBuild failed to create .xap when building cordova-wp8 for debugging.
Error: C:\Users\User\Documents\PhoneGap\hello\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Can't seem to find the problem for this.
I can build the app on Android, BlackBerry, and WP7, but cant seem to do it on WP8.

Any ideas?
Still trying to find solution.

Comment: Still haven't fixed this thing. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution
I installed Visual studio 2013 Update 2 and everything worked.